# Communication with an API

Tags: angularjs

I have a Symfony2 API and an AngularJS app which consumes it.

I'm facing a problem when trying to connect a member. It should work like this :

- The client sends a POST request to the API, on the route /api/public/users/connection. The content of the request is a JSON object like this : `{"username":"qzdqzd","password":"qzdqzdc"}`
- The server verifies the request and send back either a 400 response, with a body containing the error message (such as "This username does not exist."), or a 200 response, with the API key in the content to be stored in a cookie.

I'm facing a very strange problem. I have two instances of the API : one in my computer, in local, and the other one on the web (http://api.galaxia-online.com). When my AngularJS code is configured to request the local API, it works as expected :

[image: It works]

It's in french, but you can see in red the error message.

But when I change my AngularJS code to request the distant API, with the same request, I receive a 400 error code, but with **no content** in the response. Plus, Firefox tells me that I have a CORS problem.

I thought at first that I misconfigured CORS on the server, but! When I try to do the exact same request with a dedicated browser addon (RESTClient in my case), it works perfectly :

[image: You can see in the response the error message]

So I start to think that the problem could be caused by AngularJS. The request seems valid, and seems to work as it do in RESTClient, but AngularJS doesn't receive anything.

I'll be grateful if someone has a clue.

Comment: RESTClient can do requests that a browser can't do. It's not a good check for CORS.

Comment: Ok, so how could I check? I use Symfony2 for the API, I have the same config for CORS Bundle (NelmioCorsBundle) in local and online.

Comment: The response you posted indicates the username did not exist?  That sort of implies that CORS is not the problem but rather that your server does not have the proper users?

Comment: look right at the headers in the actual request in browser dev tools

Comment: It is clearly a CORS issue, Config your server to support CORS. Remember tools such as postman, curl etc do not reply on CORS but javascript does.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to dig deeper with a Symfony2-tagged question. Thanks.